# Why lowering of vapour pressure is not a colligative property?

Tags: solutions

In my textbook, it is written that lowering of vapour pressure is not a colligative property but relative lowering of vapour pressure is a colligative property. But why is that? There is literally no explanation given in my textbook as to why this is true. Please someone explain. I am so confused. Please help.
(By lowering of vapour pressure I mean $P_{0} - P_{S}$ where $P_{0}$ is the vapour pressure of pure solvent and $P_{S}$ is the vapour pressure of the solvent containing non-volative solute. Relative Lowering in Vapour Pressure means $\frac{P_{0} - P_{S}}{P_{0}}$).

Comment: Could you clarify with respect to the difference between 'relative lowering' and 'lowering'?

Comment: Consider reporting the whole sentences

Comment: Yeah, like @Alchimista said, please give us the complete quote;  plus please include a full citation to the textbook (author, name, publication year, publisher, edition, etc.).

Comment: Both 'lowering of vapour pressure' and 'relative lowering of vapour pressure' are colligative properties.

Comment: In my textbook of Maharashtra state board it is mentioned that both lowering in vapor pressure and rative lowering in vap pressure are colligative properties.

Answer (score 1):

A colligative property is a property which depends on number of solute particles and not on nature of solute particles. Relative lowering in vapour pressure is equal to the mole fraction of the solute . This can be derived using $P_s=P_0\cdot x_\text{solvent}$ where $x$ is the mole fraction and Po is the vapour pressure of pure solvent. Lowering of vapour pressure is also a colligative property as it is equal to $\frac{x_\text{solute}}{P_0}$. $P_0$ is a property of the solvent, not the solute.